# Laravel ErrorPlugin Required Upgrade

Tags: laravel

I have laravel 6 and t[image]his happens just suddenly.  Running `composer update` didn't help.

Comment: Are you running on WSL?

Comment: use  "composer dumpautoload"

Comment: Can you share a composer.json file with us?